# Transferring  files directly between Tablet and Phone

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, file-transfer, usb-host-mode

I want to copy files between my tablet (Toshiba AT100 with Android 4.0) and phone (Samsung Nexus S with Android 4.1) using the USB cable.

The tablet has a USB host port and once connected, the phone senses the host and asks to go into USB Storage mode. All looks good, select copy on the tablet, navigate to the mounted USB0 and to the desitred folder on the phone. However, selecting paste gives an access error. I assume it is a permission error. How do I fix this and allow the transfer. Do I need certain file explorer apps or is there a setting?

Comment: Are any of your devices rooted? (It might help if the requesting part is)

Comment: I have not rooted either of these devices.

Comment: If there is bluetooth on both devices, by using bluetooth you can choose what to copy using this tool called [DroidCopy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmad.droidcopy.server) **Disclaimer** I am associated with this app :)

Answer (score 1):

You nay also want to try using a variety of file transfer programs like Soft Data Cable or [ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5lc3Ryb25ncy5hbmRyb2lkLnBvcCJd); both of which should be able to transfer via Bluetooth, or over Wifi (ftp, etc) if you connect them on the same network.

Another alternative may be using a USB hosting app such as [stick mount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount&hl=en) but requires root access!